# Having problems with bootstrapping

Tags: connection

```
3/14/19, 17:30:15.111 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:30:15.111 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:30:15.111 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:30:15.111 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:30:15.111 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:30:15.112 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/14/19, 17:30:15.112 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/home/mike/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1" 
3/14/19, 17:30:15.112 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/14/19, 17:30:17.448 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
3/14/19, 17:30:17.534 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
3/14/19, 17:30:17.662 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
3/14/19, 17:30:19.861 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
3/14/19, 17:31:29.790 [NOTICE] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit 4 (a General-purpose client 1-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 60000ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 
3/14/19, 17:32:41.248 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
3/14/19, 17:32:41.785 [NOTICE] The current consensus has no exit nodes. Tor can only build internal paths, such as paths to onion services. 
3/14/19, 17:32:41.785 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths 
3/14/19, 17:32:41.786 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6625, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of end bw (no exits in consensus, using mid) = 0% of path bw.) 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.497 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 3B5C6ED2C1DECEB32BF1AD9B7B272F4CE9CE0656 at 89.249.65.153:443) 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.498 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.499 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.518 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.519 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.519 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host BCC94CDF386887FC10365152104978ADED8DDDEA at 164.132.228.61:443) 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.519 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.519 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.519 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.521 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 9EA4649400C7D35E20C734FA737CF615E925F1E4 at 108.61.99.149:443) 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.521 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.522 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.522 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:35:15.522 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.445 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.445 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.445 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.445 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.445 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.780 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host 07F5D725E456EDC1D84115DE7299F5B994F5D97B at 80.240.28.19:443) 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.781 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.781 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.781 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.781 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.801 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.801 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.801 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host D24D0C28AB48768CF8B79DD762D61DB4FD015677 at 109.70.100.14:443) 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.801 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.801 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.801 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.801 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.802 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host 6565F31D9EC0C7DFFEA1920BE3BA4C73EF35B5C4 at 158.69.207.216:9001) 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.802 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.802 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.802 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.802 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.803 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host 380C8120BD819DF8AC22B7D7CDE65B03C90607BE at 129.100.38.88:9001) 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.803 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.803 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.803 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.803 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.804 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.804 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host B411027C926A9BFFCF7DA91E3CAF1856A321EFFD at 51.15.76.56:443) 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.804 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.804 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.804 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.804 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.805 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.805 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host 9F5068310818ED7C70B0BC4087AB55CB12CB4377 at 81.7.11.96:443) 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.805 [WARN] 18 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.805 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.805 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.805 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:37:11.806 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.746 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.746 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.746 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.746 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.746 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.760 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 19; recommendation warn; host 6058AA626D4C67737D869E49D403425423F92AE1 at 148.251.46.49:80) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.760 [WARN] 19 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.760 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.760 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.760 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.760 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.779 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 20; recommendation warn; host 52BFADA8BEAA01BA46C8F767F83C18E2FE50C1B9 at 85.25.159.65:80) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.779 [WARN] 20 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.779 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.779 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.779 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.779 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.784 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.784 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.784 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 21; recommendation warn; host E64625ED5B01A1F0E97BCF0B5D431A432A24F408 at 128.39.8.29:443) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.784 [WARN] 22 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.784 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.784 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.785 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.785 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.785 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.785 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 22; recommendation warn; host BE0757BE6720A2B43DF0072B7CCE0583FCDD9E3A at 95.141.35.15:443) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.785 [WARN] 25 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.785 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.786 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.786 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.786 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.786 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.786 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 23; recommendation warn; host 1079E628FC6B0025656AC024F2D9975C441498CD at 51.15.185.201:443) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.786 [WARN] 26 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.786 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.787 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.787 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.787 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.787 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.788 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 24; recommendation warn; host 1A020A414D8AB25F54415C8C1E75A5562A9DD9A6 at 37.187.103.54:443) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.788 [WARN] 28 connections have failed: 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.788 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.788 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.788 [WARN]  4 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.788 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
3/14/19, 17:38:18.789 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read server session ticket A in HANDSHAKE
```

Comment: Have you tried bridges?